# Is is disk space shared between ECS Containers

Tags: amazon-ecs

I have a simple question but cannot seem to find an answer in the AWS docs.

I'm running container instances on AWS ECS.  Can anyone tell me how hard disk space is allocated to containers by default?  Do all containers simply share the available hard disk space from the underlying EC2 instance or is this configurable somehow?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different AMIs will configure this differently, by default, [the Amazon ECS-optimized Amazon Linux AMI ships](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-ami-storage-config.html) with 30 GiB of total storage. There is an additional 22-GiB volume that is attached at /dev/xvdcz that Docker uses for image and metadata storage. You can extend the Docker logical volume (see link).